# Is it possible to get data from a HDD with a missing PCB?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have an old maxtor 3.5" IDE drive that is missing the PCB. I have no idea what happened to it. The drive is nearly 20 years old and has been sitting in a drawer for years.

I recently lost my beloved dog, and wanted to find every picture/video of her that I ever had. I know of some videos that I couldn't find, and I'm hoping maybe they're on that hard drive. Is there any way to get access to it?

I contacted a website that sells replacement PCB's and gave them all the details, and they said they couldn't help. Maybe there's something that can be done though? Here are the details from various labels on the drive:

- Model: 91741U4
- HDA: 04A
- PCBA: 05A
- Unique: 13A
- Code: FA570480
- Cylinders: 16383
- Heads: 16
- Sectors: 63J
- Jumper: J50
- Master/Single: On
- Slave: Off
- Serial Number: E406RAYC
- Manufactured 04 November 1999

On the bottom of the drive, underneath where the PCB would be, there's a sticker with a bar code. Under the bar code it says:

EC38HT-2-C *M2500DTBS9416C*

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/dsc/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=1&_nkw=91741U4&_trksid=m570.l1313&_odkw=91741U4&_osacat=0 I typed in "91741U4" on ebay and found the linked results.  That does not mean they will work but it is a start.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I can't offer much hope.

Your drive is very old but I believe this article is relevant:

https://www.hddzone.com/maxtor_pcb_swap_replacement_guide.html

The article has full information but I will cover the most important parts.

An HDD replacement PCB must be a close match to the original and the numbers that must match depend on the manufacturer. For Maxtor the important number is on the main controller IC, the largest one on the board. You have a big problem here.

Most boards have a small 8 pin ROM chip that contains important drive specific information. Usually this chip must be moved to the replacement board. Another big problem.

Things may be different for your drive but I have an old Maxtor drive from 2003 that is similar to that in the article.

A commercial data recovery service may be able to help but the cost would be very high.

Answer (score 1):

You can always go to a [hard drive data recovery lab](https://www.google.com/search?ei=weA6WrjrCo-H_QaLxb_QCg&q=hard%20drive%20data%20recovery%20lab&oq=hard%20drive%20data%20recovery%20lab&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1l4.13912.14573.0.15093.4.4.0.0.0.0.110.375.3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.4.371...0.0.hRvi6llFL-M) in your area.  Unfortunately, they are never cheap, but they should be able to recover your data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on personal experience, I'd say your chances are really slim.  I've tried to replace controller boards on hard drives with another from an *identical* make and model, and even then I could never get it to work.  (I work in the IT department of a medium-sized company, so I have access to a lot of hard drives.)